# Which Web Service protocol is the most used?

Tags: web-services, rest, soap

We all can "see" from the number of articles, news, scientific papers and questions (here!) that REST and SOAP are two highly used web services protocols, but I was wondering if there's a tangible way to know which one (if there isn't another) is the most used one, or if there's some any information about the number of applications that are using one or other.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am bordering on classifying this as off topic, but..

*[WARNING:personal opinion]*

SOAP is still used in "plain old and rigid enterprise environments".
They say it has its own merits, but nobody could convince me about it yet.

REST is a great idealistic thing, however it is nothing "rest", and, most importantly, most things that state they are "RESTful" are actually not.

[Your API Is Not RESTful](https://www.danpalmer.me/blog/your-api-is-not-restful)

That said, whilst REST is practically a buzzword, SOAP is actually standardised.

Does this justify its bloatedness? To me, it does not. I'd still go with however-much-REST-that-is. But this is just preference.

*[/WARNING]*